# UIButton - addTarget not working

Tags: ios, uibutton

Adding a button to the bottom right of the screen:

```
    UIButton *testBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [testBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(test:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    testBtn.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth - 100, screenHeight - 100, 100, 100);

    [self.view addSubview:testBtn];
```

I can see the button, and tapping it turns it blue momentarily. It just doesn't call the test: method. Why not?

EDIT - here's the target method:

```
- (void)test:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"hi");
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your test method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your instance is called `lockBtn` but you are adding a target to `btn`.
2. Your method signature may be `@selector(test)` and not `@selector(test:)`.

Comment: the lockBtn thing was a typo in my question. I have edited my post to display the target method. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Nevermind. I was adding the target to the wrong button. Copy/paste error. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be because your selector is test: instead of just test? Also, you called it lockBtn, but you used btn to reference the method call...you are referencing a different button maybe?